# Что за непонятки со static переменными

Tags: php

```
class Boo{
private static $dates = array( "d"=>date("Y"));
}
$obj=new Boo;
```

Ошибка **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' on line 2**
Почему так происходит?
Вот так все нормально:

```
class Boo{
private static $dates = array( "d"=>2009);
}
$obj=new Boo;
```

вот еще http://php.benscom.com/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php#51627

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ниже приведенного вами комментария был и намёк на ответ:

```
class Boo {
    private static $dates;

    public static function init()
    {
        self::$dates = ...;
    }
}
Boo::init();
```

Теория: [ключевое слово "static"](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php):

> Как и любая другая статическая
> переменная PHP, статические свойства
> могут инициализироваться только
> используя литерал или константу,
> выражения же недопустимы. Таким
> образом вы можете инициализировать
> статическое свойство например целым
> числом или массивом, но не сможете
> указать другую переменную, результат
> вызова функции или объект.

Answer (score 4):

При обьявлении static переменных нельзя использовать функции для вычисления их значений - `expression in not allowed as field default value`.Поэтому второй вариант у вас и работает. Вы можете присвоить нужное значение в процессе выполнения приложения.